# C# accepting only numbers

Tags: c#

I'm doing an exercise of converting fahrenheits to celsius , my question is , how can i say to the program to not accept letters when the user inputs anything? (which is supposed to be only numbers).

My code is this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FirstCsharpProgram
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //declaring the first temperature needed
            float originalFahrenheit;
            float cels;
            //Input fehrenheit degrees from the user
            Console.Write("Enter temperature (Fahrenheit): ");
            originalFahrenheit = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            cels = (((originalFahrenheit - 32) /9) * 5);
            Console.Write(originalFahrenheit + " fahrenheit = " + cels);
            Console.Write(" celsius");
            Console.Write("");



        }

    }
}
```

I would like to have the next piece of code in my program as the exercise intends to start with it

```
Console.Write("Enter temperature (Fahrenheit): ");
            originalFahrenheit = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

If you could help me proceeding  with that piece of code i would be grateful

Thank you

Comment: Look at loops and `Float.TryParse`, you'll figure it out yourself.

Comment: float.Parse will however throw a FormatException if the user does not input a number. You can simply catch it and prompt the user to enter again

Comment: Another thing would be to use a regular expression. But TryParse is the fastest way.

Comment: Only like it is , if the user inputs a letter or other character the program crashes , not letting it run normally , i would like to make and if ( originalfahrenheir != number ) do something , is it possible ?

Comment: How can i implement an TryParse there ? I'm having some bad times with that since my last programs are needing it a lot and i couldn't really understand how it works and what it needs to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out originalFahrenheit)) //Parse fail
{
    //Your error message
    return; //Exit program
}
```

Comment: I did almost what you said here , my mistake was that i thought i couldn't use the Console.ReadLine() as a string since i used this : float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) , i thought it was already converted to float number so it was not a string anymore , one question , what does the ! at the start of the if ?

Comment: ! negates the value returned by float.TryParse

Comment: TryParse returns TRUE if successful. if(!float.TryParse...) means if(TryParse NOT successful)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
static float ReadFloatFromConsole()
{
    float number;
    while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, please try again");
    }
    return number;
}
```